# (Ruby on Rails) Form_for method does not work right due to some difficulty. Cannot send the data on mysql

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to make a simple book review SNS with Rails.
But I have some problems and cannot save the data on database.
I used form_for method, but something is wrong and does not work right.

１.routing

```
            root GET    /                              homes#top
           posts GET    /posts(.:format)               posts#index
                 POST   /posts(.:format)               posts#create
        new_post GET    /posts/new(.:format)           posts#new
       edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format)      posts#edit
            post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)           posts#show
                 PATCH  /posts/:id(.:format)           posts#update
                 PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)           posts#update
                 DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)           posts#destroy
```

2. posts controller

   ```
   class PostsController < ApplicationController

     def create
       @post = Post.new(posts_params)
         if @post.save
           redirect_to("posts")
         else
           render("/posts/new")
         end
     end

    private
    def posts_params
     params.permit(:title,:author,:heading,:review)
    end
   ```

   end
3. form_for

   ```
   <%=form_for @post do |f| %>
       <%= f.text_field :title, placeholder: "book_title"%>
       <%= f.text_field :author, placeholder: "author"%>
       <%= f.text_field :heading, placeholder: "heading"%>
       <%= f.text_area :review, placeholder: "review"%>
       <button>SUBMIT</button>
   <%end%>
   ```
4. terminal

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are not permitting your parameters the right way. Please attach the log of actual `#create` action.

```
 def posts_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:title,:author,:heading,:review)
 end
```